# Go JSON Naming strategy about extends

Tags: json, go

My Go struct is like this:

```
type BaseModel struct {
    Id          string    `json:"id"`
    CreatedTime time.Time `json:"createdTime"`
    UpdatedTime time.Time `json:"updatedTime"`
    Deleted     bool      `json:"deleted"`
}

type Category struct {
    BaseModel        
    Parent    string `json:"parent"`
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    IconClass string `json:"iconClass"`
    Mark      string `json:"mark"`
}
```

I want convert `Category` to JSON like this:

```
{
  "id":"",
  "deleted":"",
  ...
  "parent":"",
  "name":""
}
```

But when I use Go's json to convert it, it gives me this:

```
{
  "Id":"",
  "Deleted":"",
  ...
  "parent":"",
  "name":"",
  ...
}
```

What should I do now?

I use under code to convert:

```html
// define
var menus []models.Category
// query from db
q.Filter("deleted__exact", false).All(&menus)
// serialize it
res, _ := json.Marshal(&menus)
s := string(res[:])
beego.Debug(s)
```

Comment: You should show us how you try to generate the JSON document you posted. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: just use golang's encoding/json.Marshal function

Comment: That I guessed. Please post your code (a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, add your convert code here. The code below works fine.

```
type BaseModel struct {
    Id          string    `json:"id"`
    CreatedTime time.Time `json:"createdTime"`
    UpdatedTime time.Time `json:"updatedTime"`
    Deleted     bool      `json:"deleted"`
}

type Category struct {
    BaseModel
    Parent    string `json:"parent"`
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    IconClass string `json:"iconClass"`
    Mark      string `json:"mark"`
}

func main() {
    data, err := json.Marshal(Category{})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(data[:]))
}
```

Output:

```
{"id":"","createdTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","updatedTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","deleted":false,"parent":"","name":"","iconClass":"","mark":""}
```